How to Stream Langchain (Create pandas dataframe agent) with Azurechatgpt results in Flask Api
I want to stream my langchain implementation as response in Flask api. The streaming is Taking place but while running the api in the postman, i can see the result only after the stream ends. I am using pandas dataframe agent from langchain combined with chatgpt.
# Initialize Azure ChatOpenAI
llm = AzureChatOpenAI(
    azure_deployment="gpt-4o",
    api_version="2024-02-15-preview",
    temperature=0,
    max_tokens=2000,
    timeout=None,
    max_retries=2,
    streaming=True,
    callbacks=[StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()],
)

# Load the Excel file into a DataFrame
df = pd.read_excel("Agent")

# Create the Pandas DataFrame agent
agent = create_pandas_dataframe_agent(
    llm,
    df,
    verbose=False,
    agent_type=AgentType.OPENAI_FUNCTIONS,
    allow_dangerous_code=True
)

@app.route('/stream', methods=['GET'])
def stream():
    
    query = """
Provide me the following results\n\n
1. TL records
import pandas as pd
.......
"""
    escaped_query = query.replace('\n', '\\n').replace('\'', '\\\'').replace('\"', '\\\"')

    # Create the payload
    payload = {
        "arguments": json.dumps({"query": escaped_query}),
        "name": "python_repl_ast"
    }

    # Convert to JSON string
    payload_json = json.dumps(payload)

    def generate():
        # Invoke the agent with the properly formatted payload
        result = agent.invoke(payload_json)
        output = result.get('output', '')

        # Streaming output chunk by chunk as JSON objects
        for line in output.splitlines():
            yield json.dumps({"response": line}) + "\n"

        # Ensure the response ends properly
        yield json.dumps({"response": "Stream complete"}) + "\n"

    return Response(generate(), content_type='text/event-stream')


If you're accessing the route from a browser, then it's not possible to for flask as flask only return template once and the template can't be updated continuously. The only way to update the frontend continuously on flask is to have a template with jQuery script that continuously communicating with the server through methods such as websocket or polling to receive updated output and then modify the html elements based on that output. You can learn more from this answer
